# Why does this Stored Procedure return NULL

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures

I'm new to SQL and I was just playing around with Stored Procedures for practice. I have this SP which is supposed to return the product of the multiplication. Instead it returns NULL, without giving an error.

```
DELIMITER $$
CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` PROCEDURE `spMultiply`(IN `n1` INT, IN `n2` INT, OUT `x` INT)
    BEGIN

    SET @nn = @n1;
    SET @mm = @n2;

    SELECT @x=@nn*@mm;

END$$
DELIMITER ;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
drop PROCEDURE `spMultiply`;
DELIMITER $$
CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` PROCEDURE `spMultiply`(IN `n1` INT, IN `n2` INT, OUT `x` INT)
    BEGIN

    SET @nn = n1;
    SET @mm = n2;

    set x:=@nn*@mm;

END$$
DELIMITER ;
call spMultiply(1,2,@x);
select @x;
```

You can try above code.

Here i had made changes at line

`SELECT @x=@nn*@mm;` to `set x:=@nn*@mm;`

Also remove **`@`** from input variable.

Definitely it will help you.